# Replacement damper for an old (2008) Rockshox Reba fork?

Tags: mountain-bike, fork, suspension, vintage

The damper for the fork on my 2008 Trek Elite 9.7 probably needs replacing but I have no idea how to do this given the fork is so old. The fork is RockShox Reba SL.

Where can I find a replacement damper?

Is it possible that newer dampers are compatible and if so how would I figure out compatibility?

Comment: Did you try contacting your local bike shop or SRAM/Rockshox customer service directly?

Comment: If you cannot source a new one, a donor shock is your most likely option. Rebas were very common in that era, and will be wearing out stanchions while dampers are pretty reliable.  Might need to buy a donor bike.

Answer (score 1):

Here's [RockShox 2008 service manual](https://www.yumpu.com/en/document/read/3235958/2008-rockshox-technical-manual-bike-componentsde) where you'll find how to assemble/disassemble your fork, and how much oil and torque to use.

Here's [RockShox 2009 spare parts catalog](https://xanadu.com.pl/doc/rockshox/2009_rockshox_spc_rev_c.pdf). Find exact part of your fork model you want to replace, then look up what other fork model/year uses the same part number.